# Number of modals duplicating each time it is opened

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that loads a form inside it. However, each time I click on the button to open the modal, it duplicates the previous number of modals. It stars with 1, then 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on...

Here's my code:

```
$('#createButton').click(function () {
    var url = $('#createModal').data('url');

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#modalContent').html(data);
        $('#createModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

```
<div id="createModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-url='@Url.Action("Create")'>
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Very thankful for any help!

EDIT:
I do have another modal in the same page, eventhough it has different id's. If I comment one of them, still get the same issue.

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" id="dialogEdit">
      <div class="modal-content" id="modalContentEdit">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menuActionsLink").click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#modalContentEdit').html(data);
            $('#editModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of the #createButton element with createButton as the id? Sometimes if you have two elements with the same ID on a page it can mess up this kind of thing.

Comment: I do, but are on different pages. The div for the modal is in the layout page and I placed a button with that ID in the pages I needed to open it.

Comment: Can you try doing `$('#createButton').on('pointerup', function()`, sometimes this works.

Comment: Yeah... it did not work. What bothers me the most is that I've already written the same code on an new application and it works just fine...

Comment: I ran into this myself some years ago and just spent 20+ mins searching through my own past questions on SO but didn't find my question re same. I think I remember it having something to do with ajax, but uncertain what. If Johnny's answer below doesn't help, you might need to post more of your code for us to find the problem. I empathize... been there...

Comment: We feel so powerless, don't we? Anyway, that is the only function where I call those id's. I do have another modal in the same page but I've set different id's

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate modal"? In your example there is no code that is able to duplicate. Except `.html(...)` ...

Comment: Each time I click the button to open, the modal duplicates de previous number. The first time it open a single modal. The second it'll open 2, the third 4, the fourth 8, the fifth 16 and so on and so on... https://gyazo.com/143a1b7eb3985913eebe87673528385f that's how many I got when clicked for the third time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED AND IMPORTANT: if we keep the Javascript in the view it works perfect!!  But when we want to place the javascript in a javascript file so that we can call from all views the same functions , it does that bug!!!! anyone knows why???
this also means its not about having duplicated code!

SOLUTION:

Do not call the function as click in javascript file!!!

```
function tentativa1() {

        var url = $('#asd').data('url');

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#asd1').html(data);
            $('#asd').modal('show');
        });
};
```

use a normal function as you can see above, and in HTML do the on click part...

```
<button id="criarRegisto" onclick="tentativa1()">+ Create New Area</button>
```

I am new to this and i dont understand why this behaviour happens, but it works perfectly this way!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I think probably you have duplicates of one of the IDs, perhaps id="createModal" is mentioned twice in your code. In isolation this code works fine, which suggests that something else is wrong. If you are really struggling, you can check if the element already exists within that div by doing something like this to check that the element doesn't exist.

I assume that createModal is not already in modalContent. If that is the case, you can check that the length is less than 1. If it is already there, then maybe you should check `is(':visible')`.

```js
$('#createButton').click(function () {
    var url = $('#createModal').data('url');
    $.get(url, function (data) {
      if($('#modalContent #createModal').length <= 1) {
        $('#modalContent').html(data);
        $('#createModal').modal('show');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="createButton">
  Click me
</div>
```

Comment: Using ```is(:visible)``` the modal doesnt show up... What does that mean? I also added ```evt.stopImmediatePropagation()``` and it just works, althought I dont know what that line really does.

Comment: e.stopImmediatePropagation stops the click for that element from being accessed again in another event listener. Suggests you might have another piece of code somewhere - maybe you have #createButton.click twice in your code.